# Indices of square numbers that are also pentagonal

Tags: code-golf, math, number, sequence

First 15 numbers of the [A046173](https://oeis.org/A046173):

```
1, 99, 9701, 950599, 93149001, 9127651499, 894416697901, 87643708742799, 8588189040096401, 841554882220704499, 82463790268588944501, 8080609891439495856599, 791817305570802005002201, 77590015336047156994359099, 7603029685627050583442189501
```

Your task is simple, output the first 20 numbers of this sequence on separate lines.

A simple explanation to this sequence, (you can also refer to the link above), is
As n increases, this sequence is approximately geometric with common ratio \$ r = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a(n)}{a(n-1)} = (\sqrt2 + \sqrt3)^4 = 49 + 20 \times \sqrt6 \$

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins!

Comment: "You can refer to the link above" - Challenges must be self-contained. You need to specify the definition. Is the sequence always exactly the rounded version of the geometric one you include?

Comment: Why should the output be displayed on separate lines? Why not just rely on our standard I/O formats? Or is this supposed to be a [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/kolmogorov-complexity/info) challenge? (If so, I guess the largest results should not be approximated, but that should be clearly specified.)

Comment: arnauld if you want please edit my post then

Comment: Since, according to the OEIS, this sequence is given by \$a(n) = 98 \cdot a(n-1) - a(n-2)\$, this is a [chameleon challenge](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8214/20260) for a Fibonacci variant. of which we've had lots of similar challenges.

Comment: I've closed this as needing clarity but based on xnor's comment this is probably a duplicate of an existing fibonacci challenge.

Comment: The formula you given is property of given sequence but not the definition of it. For example: You can say, "except first item, all items are odd" for ["prime numbers"](https://oeis.org/A000040) sequence. But you cannot list prime numbers only based on it.

Comment: If you are only requiring output first 20 items. I would suggest you simply include all 20 items in your post so everyone may verify their correctness by easily comparing with given results.

Comment: why can't i delete this qns?

Comment: cuz basically all im doing rn is accumulating negative points

Comment: I suggest you use [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?answertab=active) before posting, so all issues are resolved there, not on the main site.

Comment: @DialFrost You cannot delete a question with any answers that have upvotes. This is why it's recommended to go through the Sandbox first, so that you avoid losing reputation that happens from posting unclear challenges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

With strict I/O as defined in the challenge description: the first 20 items newline delimited:

```
21®1‚λ£98*s-}¦»
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ASAA3/9vc2FiaWX//zIxwq4x4oCazrvCozk4KnMtfcKmwrv//w)

With default [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) I/O rules: outputs the 1-based \$n^{th}\$ term (**10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)**):

```
®1‚λè98*s-
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0DrDRw2zzu0@vMLSQqtY9/9/Q1MA)

**Explanation:**

Uses the formula: \$a(n)=98\times a(n-1)-a(n-2)\$ with offset \$-1,1\$, the first formula defined on [the oeis-page](https://oeis.org/A046173).

```python
     λ       # Start a recursive environment,
21    £      # to get the first 21 terms
  ®1‚        # Starting with a(0)=-1 and a(1)=1
             # With every following a(n) defined as:
       98*   #  Multiply the implicit a(n-1) by 98
          s- #  Subtract the implicit a(n-2) from it
     }¦      # After the recursive environment: remove the first -1 term
       »     # Join the 20 terms by newlines
             # (after which it is output implicitly as result)

   λ         # Start a recursive environment,
    è        # to output the (implicit) input'th term
®1‚          # Starting with a(0)=-1 and a(1)=1
             # With every following a(n) defined as:
     98*s-   #  Same as above: 98*a(n-1)-a(n-2)
             # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 22 bytes

```
λ²`(3ṙ-x)/2`∆qt:⌊=;20ȯ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJqIiwiIiwizrvCsmAoM+G5mS14KS8yYOKIhnF0OuKMij07MjDIryIsIiIsIjEiXQ==)

Finally a good use for symbolic algebra in a golfing language. Good luck porting this to Jelly lol.

### Explained

```
λ²`...`∆qt:⌊=;20ȯ
λ                 # Create a lambda, that takes a single argument n and:
 ²                #   squares n
 `...`            #   pushes the string "(3x^2-x)/2" (this is the formula for pentagonal numbers - I found it on Wikipedia) 
      ∆q          #   and solves that for x (as in, it uses Sympy to solve it as if it were an equation) - this will give a list of up to 2 solutions - a negative and positive solution in that order
        t         #   Push that positive solution because that's what we're interested in checking
         :⌊=      #   Does the floor of that solution equal that solution? This checks to see if it's an integer solution, as only integer solutions are plugged into the original formula anyway
            ;     # Close the lambda
             20ȯ  # and push the first 20 numbers where that lambda is truthy - this times out online, but it works given infinite time and resources
# The j flag joins that list on newlines - I think it's okay here because the main focus of the challenge is generating the numbers
```

Comment: lyxal would you be kind enough to explain the code?

Comment: @dialfrost that's what I'm working on now :)

Comment: ah ic sry lol i like how ur name is similar to the language :)

Comment: @dialfrost it's what I call an inability to name things creatively :p

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 50 bytes

A full program.

```javascript
for(v=q=1n;~v%39n;v=q-98n*(q=-v))console.log(v+'')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/Lb9Io8y20NYwz7quTNXYMs8ayNO1tMjT0ii01S3T1EzOzyvOz0nVy8lP1yjTVlfX/P8fAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 44 bytes

```
for(i=0,19,print(([-1,1]*[0,-1;1,98]^i)[2]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/j/Py2/SCPT1kDH0FKnoCgzr0RDI1rXUMcwVivaQEfX0NpQx9IiNi5TM9ooVlPz/38A)

Using the formula \$a(n)=98\ a(n-1)-a(n-2)\$.